# Woocommerce email after product is out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to email all people who ordered a product when this product becomes out of stock?

Example: 
Product A has 15 in quantity. When it reaches 0 to sent emails to all people that ordered this product.

I've found `woocommerce_email_recipient_no_stock` hook, however I'm not sure how or if I can use it. Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. You can't purchase an item once it is out of stock, so there shouldn't be a situation where people ordered an item and then it went out of stock before you could deliver it.

Comment: Well we are trying to sell products based on crowdfunding idea i.e. when its funded (product goes out of stock) we want to send thank you emails and let them know that the product is going to be shipped in next few days.

Comment: Ahh.... I was kind of interested in building that once upon a time. Didn't know if there was any need for it.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be configured in woocommerce admin, go to WooCommerce > Notifications and click on the “Add notification” button:Enable notifications for Purchases,Low stock,Out of stock,Backorders etc.

Comment: Well this works for admin only, right? What I want is to email the users that bought this product.